# Running regression and loop through all the columns of my dataset

Tags: r

I'm running a regression in the form :

```
reg=lm(y ~ a+b+ab,data=mydata)
```

In the place of "b",I want to loop through all the columns of my dataset.
Example:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNLK6.png)

```
reg=lm(y `~` a+b+ab,data=mydata)
reg=lm(y `~` a+c+ac,data=mydata)
```

In second time, i want to loop through all the columns of my dataset for both "a" and "b".
Example:

```
reg=lm(y `~` a+b+ab,data=mydata)
reg=lm(y `~` a+c+ac,data=mydata)
reg=lm(y `~` b+c+bc,data=mydata)
reg=lm(y `~` c+d+cd,data=mydata)
reg=lm(y `~` e+c+ec,data=mydata).....all possibilities
```

Finally i want to save any output that have at least 1 significant p value.
I use R for my statistics.

Comment: Is `a + b + ab` meant to represent `a + b + I(a*b)` - i.e. - `a` multiplied by `b`? R is not a symbolic language so you have to be explicit about what is happening.

Comment: yes i want to test interaction between a and b reg=lm(y `~` a+b+a*b,data=mydata)

Comment: I believe using just `y ~ a * b` expands to `y ~ a + b + a:b` where `a:b` is the interaction term. `:` is the character for including an interaction explicitly. I suggest you might want to read up on formula specifications for R - e.g. http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/formulanotation.pdf

Comment: You probably should be searching on all-subsets regression, but you should also realize that this will be seem as egregious data-dredging by most reputable statisticians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your first loop

```
lapply(setdiff(names(mydata),c("y","a")),function(x){
lm(paste0("y~a*",x),mydata)
})
```

This should do the second

```
VariablesToLoop<-expand.grid(setdiff(names(mydata),"y"),setdiff(names(mydata),"y"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
VariablesToLoop<-VariablesToLoop[!VariablesToLoop$Var1==VariablesToLoop$Var2,]
Map(function(name1,name2){
lm(paste0("y~",name1,"*",name2),mydata)
},VariablesToLoop$Var1,VariablesToLoop$Var2)
```

Assuming all the models results are saved in the element **allmodels**, just run:

```
elementsToKeep<-sapply(allmodels,function(x){
pvalues<-summary(x)$coefficients[,4] 
ifelse(any(pvalues<0.05),TRUE,FALSE)
})

relevantmodels<-allmodels[elementsToKeep]
```

to save the relevant models in **relevantmodels**

Then in order to save:

```
relevant.pvalues<-lapply(relevantmodels,function(x){
summary(x)$coefficients[,4] 
})

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(relevant.pvalues), nrow=length(relevant.pvalues),byrow=T))

write.csv(df,file="pvalues.csv")
```

Comment: But with this code does it save any output that have at least 1 significant p value?

Comment: I want to save automatically the output in external file

Comment: What do you want to save specifically?

Comment: Saving the output of the regression (p value Estimate..)

Comment: Thanks for the modifications  when i run the first part of your script (doing regression), r crashes, may be because of the number of regressions (1000 regressions)? i wonder if the problem is that? may be if i add the function save in the begining it will solve the problem?

Comment: i dont have an error because r crashes and i have to close it. I tried with a smaller data (only 5 columns) and even it takes some time (4 minutes) but it works (give me the results)